# Magento 2.1: Default setting for "Store View"

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, store-view, scope

Whenever I edit a product, the Store View (scope) is set to "All Store Views" each time.

In my particular setup, I would like this to default to **Main Website > Main Website Store > Default Store View**, but can't find a way to do it.

Any advice? The solution can be a configuration setting or programmatic, I don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The admin link is generate by this method

[`\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions::prepareDataSource()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/ProductActions.php#L47)
As you can see there is already a line that checks for a store id

`$storeId = $this->context->getFilterParam('store_id');`.
You can write an [`around`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) plugin on this method. You will basically keep the same code but replace the line mentioned above with `$storeId = 1`(or other value if you have a different one)

Comment: That's superb - it worked a treat. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please send me around method code here @marius because I'm getting error in Magento version 2.3.3